# Extracting every frame from a video with its original timestamp (in the filename or printed on the image)

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to ask this question again because old solutions no longer work with ffmpeg 6.0, owing to a change made in [January 2023](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/260f3918937463f1b90e1b77cba80b917f3cb8c1) that prevents the use of the `-r` and `-vsync`/`-fps_mode` parameters simultaneously.

The goal is to use filenames or superposed text with images of frames, to identify their exact (presentation) timestamps in the original video, without any kinds of offsets, sanitisations, and to a user-desired precision (by default, milliseconds). Additionally, it should be possible to tell that every frame has been dumped, and sorted in timestamp order, from a specified segment of the video. *The motive is to use the video to time the durations of events recorded in it.*

The command I had previously thought solved this problem was:

```
ffmpeg
-ss 1:23:45
-t 5
-i input.mkv
-copyts
-fps_mode passthrough
-r 1000
-frame_pts 1
%08d.jpg
```

But it's apparently no longer possible to use `-fps_mode` with `-r 1000`. It seems that the image2 muxer implicitly used here defaults to a timebase of 1, and `-r 1000` was previously being used to scale the timebase to 0.001. I am unsure if `-enc_time_base 0.001` will do the same thing, and if I may need to also use `-video_track_timescale` or similar. I want to ideally extract the timestamps verbatim from the source, optionally truncated (e.g. to milliseconds) and not have to make assumptions about CFR/VFR etc. So I'd like a pro to check I'm doing this correctly. I'd also like to know how to get these same timestamps superposed on the images themselves, but haven't researched it pending getting the filenames method to work. Thanks.

*Here's an [answer by Gyan](https://superuser.com/a/1611331/1788310) suggesting the now-impossible mixture of `-vsync` and `-r`.*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a change was subsequently made to enforce CFR when `-r` is set.
`-enc_time_base 1/FPS` should be used instead.

`-video_track_timescale` is specific to MP4/MOV output.

Comment: Here's the full command that worked for me to extract scene frames from a video and include the timestamp in the filename:
ffmpeg -i "<videoPath>" -vf "select='gt(scene,0.4)'" -frame_pts true -enc_time_base 1 -vsync vfr scene-%2d.jpg